# What goes in a Web Service's 401 body?

Tags: web-services, http, authentication, http-headers

This question really applies to any non-200 and non-redirects.

For a standard HTML site, the body of a 401 response is generally HTML, letting the client know in a pretty way that they need to login.  In the case of Java, at least, you can provide a message when you throw a 401, and that msg is displayed in the client.

What (if any) is the standard way of sending that message down to the client in the case of a web service?  Is the contents of the body application specific?  Is there a standard header where that information could live, in which case the body would be empty?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

All information needed to authenticate should be in the WWW-Authenticate response header field.